# Programmatically set api_key when using pybraries (Libaries.io API)

Tags: python, python-3.x, libraries

I'm trying to use libraries.io apis in my research project. From their official doc https://pybraries.readthedocs.io/en/latest/README.html, they only mentioned about setting api_key as an env variable. I wonder if there is a programmatically way to set the api_key in my source code? Any inputs is welcome, thanks in advance.

Btw, I've tried to add my api_key(got it from libraries.io) as env variable, but it is not working either.

```
from pybraries.search import Search

search = Search()

info = search.project_search(keywords='visualization', sort='stars', platform='pypi')
print(info)
```

but I got this error:

```
pybraries.helpers.APIKeyMissingError: All methods require an API key. See https://libraries.io to get your free key. Then set the key to the environment variable: LIBRARIES_API_KEY
```

When I check my env variables on my mbp, I actually can see LIBRARIES_API_KEY set correctly.

Comment: you could dig in [source code](https://github.com/pybraries/pybraries/tree/master/pybraries) to see if you can set it in different way. OR if you can get some part of code and change it. You can also send `pull request` on this page and ask for changes in code.

Comment: you can check what values you have in `os.environ`